# How to get my program to start over when the user hits "y" on

Tags: java, loops, system.out

So I've used `System.out.print("Enter more test scores? (y/n): ");` yet when I run it and all the  scores are summarizes the user isn't given the chance to do it again here is  my code. Do you guys think I may have put it in the wrong place.

```
public class TestScoreApp

{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // display operational messages

        System.out.println("Please enter the number of test scores to be entered");

        System.out.println("To end the program enter 999.");

        System.out.println();  // print a blank line





        int scoreTotal = 0;

        int scoreCount = 0;

        int testScore = 0;

        int min = 100;

        int max = 0;

        int counter = 0;

        int setNumber = 0;

        String userAnswer = "n";

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);



        // get a series of test scores from the user



        outerLoop:

        do {

            // user enters number of test scores to be entered

            System.out.print("Enter the number of test scores to be entered: ");

            setNumber = sc.nextInt();

            if (setNumber > 0 && setNumber != 999)

            {

                while (setNumber > 0)

                {

                // user enters test scores   

                System.out.print("Enter score: ");

                testScore = sc.nextInt();



                    // accumulate score count and score total



                    if (testScore <= 100)

                    {      

                        scoreCount += 1;

                        scoreTotal += testScore;

                        setNumber --;



                    } //Added for Exercise 2-2, #4 modified if statement

                    else if (testScore > 100 || testScore < 0) {

                        System.out.println("Invalid entry, score not counted");

                   } else if (testScore == 999) {

                        System.out.println("Average test score complete");

                    }



                    if (testScore > max && testScore <= 100) {

                        max = testScore;

                    }

                    if (testScore < min && testScore >= 0) {

                        min = testScore;

                    }

                    if (setNumber == counter)

                    {

                        break outerLoop;


                    }

                //End of test scores while loop

                }



                userAnswer = sc.next();



            }

            }// end of do loop

        while(userAnswer.compareTo("y") == 0 );

            System.out.print("Enter more test scores? (y/n): ");

       // display the score count, score total, and average score

        // Added casting from int ot double Exercise 3-2 #5

         double averageScore = (double) scoreTotal / (double) scoreCount;



         // Added number formatting ( 1 decimal place) 

        NumberFormat number = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();

        number.setMaximumFractionDigits(1);



        String message = "\n"

                + "Score count:   " + scoreCount + "\n"

                + "Score total:   " + scoreTotal + "\n"

                + "Average score: " + averageScore + "\n"

                //Added for Exercise 3-2 #4 add min/max

                + "Max score: " + max + "\n"

                + "Min score: " + min + "\n";





        System.out.println(message);



    }      

}
```

Comment: I imagine you want to move `System.out.print("Enter more test scores? (y/n): ");` to just **above** where it says `userAnswer = sc.next();`, otherwise your asking for the answer before you've asked the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several modifications to be done in the program.

1. `When you are asking user to enter the choice for inputting more, you should accept his/her choice in your userAnswer variable before closing off the do-while loop SO THAT THE USER CHOICE CAN BE CHECKED AFTER EACH ITERATION!`
2. `There is no need to break the OUTER-LOOP without checking user's input!`
3. `scoreCount & scoreTotal need to be initialised with 0 again in the beginning of the do-while loop.`

The corrected program along with the imports needed :-

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication7 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println("Please enter the number of test scores to be entered");
System.out.println("To end the program enter 999.");
System.out.println();  // print a blank line
int scoreCount = 0,scoreTotal = 0;
int testScore = 0;
int min = 100;
int max = 0;
int counter = 0;
int setNumber = 0;
String userAnswer = "n";
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
// get a series of test scores from the user
do {
    // user enters number of test scores to be entered
    System.out.print("Enter the number of test scores to be entered: ");
    setNumber = sc.nextInt();
    if (setNumber > 0 && setNumber != 999)
    {
        scoreCount=0;
             scoreTotal=0;
        while (setNumber > 0)
        {
        // user enters test scores   
        System.out.print("Enter score: ");
        testScore = sc.nextInt();
            if (testScore <= 100)
            {      
                scoreCount += 1;
                scoreTotal += testScore;
                setNumber --;
            } //Added for Exercise 2-2, #4 modified if statement
            else if (testScore > 100 || testScore < 0) {
                System.out.println("Invalid entry, score not counted");
            } else if (testScore == 999) {
                System.out.println("Average test score complete");
            }
            if (testScore > max && testScore <= 100) {
                max = testScore;
            }
            if (testScore < min && testScore >= 0) {
                min = testScore;
            }
        }
       // display the score count, score total, and average score
// Added casting from int ot double Exercise 3-2 #5
 double averageScore = (double) scoreTotal / (double) scoreCount;
 // Added number formatting ( 1 decimal place) 
NumberFormat number = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
number.setMaximumFractionDigits(1);
String message = "\n"
        + "Score count:   " + scoreCount + "\n"
        + "Score total:   " + scoreTotal + "\n"
        + "Average score: " + averageScore + "\n"
        //Added for Exercise 3-2 #4 add min/max
        + "Max score: " + max + "\n"
        + "Min score: " + min + "\n";
System.out.println(message); 
    }
    System.out.print("Enter more test scores? (y/n): ");
    userAnswer=sc.next();     // Single Error----Only corrected piece of code.
    }while(userAnswer.compareTo("y") == 0 );    
// end of do loop
}
```

}

Comment: @Jat - Kindly check the answer that I have amended for you; it's working fine in my system. I hope you are satisfied and please favour by doing an upvote or accepting the answer!!!

Answer (score 1):

I dont know what exactly you want to do, if you want to ask if the user want to add more scores after the default scores (that user set on beggining) so this is the answer:

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestScoreApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // display operational messages
        System.out.println("Please enter the number of test scores to be entered");
        System.out.println("To end the program enter 999.");
        System.out.println(); // print a blank line

        // declarations
        int scoreTotal = 0;
        int scoreCount = 0;
        int testScore = 0;
        int min = 100;
        int max = 0;
        int counter = 0;
        int setNumber = 0;
        String userAnswer = "n";
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        // get a series of test scores from the user

        // outerLoop:
        // do {

        // user enters number of test scores to be entered
        System.out.print("Enter the number of test scores to be entered: ");

        setNumber = sc.nextInt();

        if (setNumber > 0 && setNumber != 999) {
            do { // put the loop condition below

                // user enters test scores
                System.out.print("Enter score: ");

                testScore = sc.nextInt();

                // accumulate score count and score total
                if (testScore <= 100) {
                    scoreCount += 1;
                    scoreTotal += testScore;
                    setNumber--;
                } // Added for Exercise 2-2, #4 modified if statement
                else if (testScore > 100 || testScore < 0) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid entry, score not counted");
                } else if (testScore == 999) {
                    System.out.println("Average test score complete");
                }
                if (testScore > max && testScore <= 100) {
                    max = testScore;
                }
                if (testScore < min && testScore >= 0) {
                    min = testScore;
                }

                // if (setNumber == counter) {
                // break outerLoop;
                // }

                if (setNumber == counter) { // test if the counter reached zero
                    System.out.print("Enter more test scores? (y/n): "); // ask if the user want to add more
                    userAnswer = new Scanner(System.in).next(); // read the input
                    if (userAnswer.toCharArray()[0] == 'y') { // if yes, do
                        setNumber += 1;     // add +1 to setNumber, so user can add more one score
                    }
                }
            } while (setNumber > 0);
        }
        // display the score count, score total, and average score
        // Added casting from int ot double Exercise 3-2 #5
        double averageScore = (double) scoreTotal / (double) scoreCount;

        // Added number formatting ( 1 decimal place)
        NumberFormat number = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
        number.setMaximumFractionDigits(1);

        String message = "\n" + "Score count:   " + scoreCount + "\n"
                + "Score total:   " + scoreTotal + "\n" + "Average score: "
                + averageScore + "\n"
                // Added for Exercise 3-2 #4 add min/max
                + "Max score: " + max + "\n" + "Min score: " + min + "\n";
        System.out.println(message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are asking the user:

```
 System.out.print("Enter more test scores? (y/n): ");
```

after you exit from the while loop. This won't work. Just put this line exactly before:

```
userAnswer = sc.next();
```